# Default Constructor issue while using Jackson Parser

Tags: android, android-studio, jackson, android-gradle-plugin

My model getter setter class looks like this:-

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CuratedOffers {
    public CuratedOffers() {
    }

    @JsonProperty("response")
    private String response;
    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Data mData;
    public Data getmData() {
        return mData;
    }
    public void setmData(Data mData) {
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Data{


        @JsonProperty("vendors")
        private List<Vendor> vendorList;
        public List<Vendor> getVendorList() {
            return vendorList;
        }
        public void setVendorList(List<Vendor> vendorList) {
            this.vendorList = vendorList;
        }
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Vendor {



        @JsonProperty("id")
        private String Id;
        public String getId() {
            return Id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            Id = id;
        }



        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String venName;
        public String getVenName() {
            return venName;
        }
        public void setVenName(String venName) {
            this.venName = venName;
        }

        @JsonProperty("image")
        private String image;
        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }
        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @JsonProperty("logo")
        private String logo;
        public String getLogo() {
            return logo;
        }
        public void setLogo(String logo) {
            this.logo = logo;
        }


        @JsonProperty("offers")
        private String offers;
        public String getOffers() {
            return offers;
        }
        public void setOffers(String offers) {
            this.offers = offers;
        }

        @JsonProperty("description")
        private String offer_description;
        public void setOffer_description(String offer_description) {
            this.offer_description = offer_description;
        }
        public String getOffer_description() {
            return offer_description;
        }
    }
}
```

And i using Jackson while compiling through gradle ie:-

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'
```

After compiling i keep getting this error in my stacktrace

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.yoy.CuratedOffers$Data]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
```

Searched SO without any suitable answers.Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried to make the Data class static and/or declare public constructor?

Comment: @vilpe89 Thanks buddy solved my own question.Thanks a ton mate.Will answer in a while!Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @vilpel89 i had forgot to declare a static nested class inside CuratedOffers class.Now my updated class is:-

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CuratedOffers {
    public CuratedOffers() {
    }

    @JsonProperty("response")
    private String response;
    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Data mData;
    public Data getmData() {
        return mData;
    }
    public void setmData(Data mData) {
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Data{
        public Data() {
        }

        @JsonProperty("vendors")
        private List<Vendor> vendorList;
        public List<Vendor> getVendorList() {
            return vendorList;
        }
        public void setVendorList(List<Vendor> vendorList) {
            this.vendorList = vendorList;
        }
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Vendor {

        public Vendor() {
        }

        @JsonProperty("id")
        private String Id;
        public String getId() {
            return Id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            Id = id;
        }



        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String venName;
        public String getVenName() {
            return venName;
        }
        public void setVenName(String venName) {
            this.venName = venName;
        }

        @JsonProperty("image")
        private String image;
        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }
        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @JsonProperty("logo")
        private String logo;
        public String getLogo() {
            return logo;
        }
        public void setLogo(String logo) {
            this.logo = logo;
        }


        @JsonProperty("offers")
        private String offers;
        public String getOffers() {
            return offers;
        }
        public void setOffers(String offers) {
            this.offers = offers;
        }

        @JsonProperty("description")
        private String offer_description;
        public void setOffer_description(String offer_description) {
            this.offer_description = offer_description;
        }
        public String getOffer_description() {
            return offer_description;
        }
    }
}
```

Added a static constructor to my Data class as well as Vendor Class and also added default constructors to it.Now it's working like a charm!Hope it might help someone someday!